# What causes color change on the surface of blade in picture?

Tags: visible-light, wavelength, metals

What causes this color distribution in the knife shown below? A chemical that causes light to change wavelength? A product of the heating process?

[image: Colored Knife]

[image]

Comment: Do the colors change if you look at them from a different angle?

Comment: No. I'll add more pictures

Answer (score 6):

This looks to me like an example thin film interference.  It can produced when steel is heated and a thin iron oxide layer is produced on the surface.  Different temperatures produced different thicknesses of oxide which leads to interference maxima at different wavelengths (colors).

In this case it was more likely done by deliberately depositing a thin film on the steel, possibly of titanium oxide, by means of [anodization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anodizing).

[Here's a good one pager](http://www.mrtitanium.com/interference.html) on the physics involved.

Comment: I did not, but this was probably done as part of the Blake's production process. Thank you!